# add parse articles

Tags: php

I am making parser of articles and I have one problem. When I parse them it is all ok, it is showing all articles that I need, but when I try to add them to database I am getting some problems.

Every upload on page adds one article to database, but not in one upload all articles. Why?

I need to add all articles in one upload but not by adding one article in each upload of the page. Help me please

Code:

```html
<?

    require '../db/database.php';
    require 'phpQuery/phpQuery.php'; 
  define('HOST','url');

 $data_site = file_get_contents(HOST);
 $document = phpQuery::newDocument($data_site);
 $content_prev = $document->find('.td-animation-stack');

 foreach ($content_prev as $el) {
    $pq = pq($el);
    $title = $pq->find('h3 a')->html();
    $link = $pq->find('h3 a')->attr('href');

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM article_test WHERE title=?");
$stmt->execute([$title]); 
$data = $stmt->fetch();
if (!$data) {

    
  try {
   $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO article_test (title) VALUES (:title)');
   $stmt->execute(array(
    ':title' => $title
    ));
   exit;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}


}
```

Comment: I didnt unerstand anything from your question, but I have a guess using `':title' => $data['title']` might help. also `if (!$data) { Should echo error not display insert query }`

Comment: @dilek koç I need to make script that is adding all data from the parser to the database

Comment: Change `if (!$data)` to `if ($data)` if not work then search : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+parse+article+